# Cannot install AMD graphics driver

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, graphics-card

I had AMD graphics installed on my windows 7 laptop. Last week, I performed a clean install of windows 8.1 and since I could not change brightness and other display settings (well, I could change the settings, but the display would not adjust to it), I figured I had to update the display drivers.

The AMD graphics 13.9 could not be installed:

[image]

Nothing enlightening in the log.

I went to the device manager and uninstalled the driver. Upon restarting the computer, I noticed that there is a generic MS driver there:

[image]

Tried to install the AMD driver and it failed again. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: You may try [AMD auto-detect-tool](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/auto-detect-tool)

Comment: I've already tried it and just did it again to be sure, but it did not work: http://i1288.photobucket.com/albums/b498/capadocia7/Untitled4_zps20725aa5.png

Comment: I'd start with trying to fix those three `Unknown device` entries first.  You may be missing system drivers, which could be affecting other things.  Check with your manufacturer for chipset and other drivers.

Comment: try the 13.11 (beta) driver: http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/latest-catalyst-windows-beta.aspx You must run the mobility download tool to get the driver.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall driver USB 3.0,
restart PC,
install AMD driver and restart PC, after update Windows for sound
(Advanced Micro Device)
now install driver USB 3.0

Comment: Uninstall a driver, please do not just delete it.